# Python | Error sending email using python and html form. No email arrives

Tags: python

I am developing a website, and on one page it has a contact form like almost all websites. But it has an error sending email using python and html form. No email arrives. Where is the error? Thanks!

**File** contact.html

```
<form action="main.py" method="get" id="contact_form" class="contact_form clearfix">
    <input type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Name" required="required" name="name">
    <input type="email" class="contact_input" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" name="email">
    <input type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Subject" required="required" name="subject">
    <textarea class="contact_input contact_textarea" placeholder="Text" required="required" name="text"></textarea>
    <button class="contact_button">Send</button>
</form>
```

**File** main.py

```
import os
import smtplib
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name =  form.getvalue('name')
email =  form.getvalue('email')
subject =  form.getvalue('subject')
text =  form.getvalue('text')

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import smtplib 

sender = email 
addressee = "myemail@gmail.com" 
subject = subject 
text = text

email = """From: %s 
To: %s 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-type: text/html 
Subject: %s 

%s
""" % (sender, addressee, subject, text) 
try: 
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('localhost') 
    smtp.sendmail(sender, addressee, email) 
    print "Email sent" 
except: 
    print """Error: the message could not be sent."""
```

Comment: Did you check the log of the mail server? Is the `Email sent` printed?

Comment: I have only checked if emails arrive in gmail.

Comment: Unless you're still on python 2, the `print "something"` needs parentheses. Oh, and you may want to add `import cgitb; cgitb.enable()` to the start of main.py then lose the `try` and `except` temporarily until you get the problem sorted.

Comment: You may then want to test main.py using curl from the terminal/command prompt via `curl -i -o - "http://localhost:8000/htbin/main.py?name=sadf&email=asdf%40foo.com&subject=asdf&text=asdf"`